# Do I need all drupal core history in my own repository

Tags: version-control

I decided to update core via git, mostly by following the approach explained [here](http://cweagans.net/blog/2011/10/14/my-drupalgit-workflow).

I did this (in my local repo, dev branch):

```
git remote add core git://drupalcode.org/project/drupal.git 
git fetch core
git merge 7.21 
(resolved few conflicts)
git commit --amend
drush updatedb
```

I did this for the sake of making it easy to update core in the future, as proposed:

```
git fetch core 
git merge [new commit hash]
```

- Am I adding too much to my project by fetching all core history, or is this needed? I am interested only in updating core in my existing project.
- If so, can I get rid of the core history?
- Can I in next core update fetch only by tag?

Comment: Thanks for edits kiamlaluno, have not spotted that i messed up code formatting :)

Answer (score 1):

[Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/803746) suggests a similar approach.  But, I'm not sure I understand the need to keep core's history under your own repo either. Or any code you yourself didn't create or amend.

Why not just have your repo at /sites/?  And have your ignore file leave out anything you haven't touched, including unmodified modules from drupal.org (and all the stuff in /sites/default/files/). Then you're workflow could be to use drush to update core, modules and themes and use git for all your own code.  Use `drush rsync` for files when working between local, dev, stage and production.

Side note: I'm glad to see this question here because this is something I've been wondering myself and though I don't use the approach I've just suggested, I'm thinking about it.

Comment: This seems like a good proposal. But I do not how idea how I should do it best way. How would i efficiently maintain repo in repo. If you would use this way, how would you implement it? Thanks!